# How do you specify a range for the z-dimension when using ezsurf() function?

Tags: matlab

According to this site: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezsurf.html

ezsurf takes parameters:

```
ezsurf(f,[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
```

However, if I want to specify a zmin and zmax, how do I do that?

I am trying to graph:

```
f(x,y)=sqrt(x^2+y^2)
ezsurf(f, [0,10,0,10])
```

which works perfectly except it goes above z=10.  I'm trying to chop it off at right at z=10. How do I do that?

I'm not tied to using ezsurf(). If there's another function out there that can do this, I'm ok with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to specify the [z limits of the axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zlim.html) which will automatically chop the surface off at the upper and lower limits that you specify.

```
ezsurf(f, [0 10 0 10])
set(gca, 'zlim', [0 10])
```

[image]